# Windows printer driver update functionality

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, printer

I have a question about the driver-selection dialog in the Windows add-printer-menu. What exactly does the Windows Update button do there, aren't new printer models added during the normal windows update process? (for example in win10 All Settings/Update&Security/Windows Update/Check for Updates). 
Is he checking a special Driver-Repository or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Just because a manufacturer makes a new printer or releases a new driver does not mean that driver is automatically published to Microsoft and then made available via Windows update.

Microsoft receives drivers from printer manufacturers to choose to communicate with Microsoft, and then Microsoft evaluates the drivers carefully, and if they pass inspection these will be included in Windows Update.

These drivers are not usually the latest, but they can usually be relied on to be quite stable.

When you connect a printer that the local system does not yet have a driver for, Windows can search the online repository if you allow it (the default setup is to do this automatically, I believe) and then download and install the appropriate driver for the new printer. If the driver is not found online, then you will be required to insert the disk that came with the printer.

Additionally, it is not likely that Microsoft takes the time to add to the default driver list on the system via Windows update. I have not personally witnessed this myself, at any rate. Drivers included in the original OS tend to be compact and include only very basic features of the printer. Most modern printers have loads of features and have very large driver packages. It would be a waste of space to try to include these in basic Windows installs that do not even have that printer.